# Move data points with mouse in line chart rendered with Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart rendered with Chart.js 2.4.0.

According to the business requirement, the user should be able to move data points shown in the line chart using the mouse. Particularly, clicking the data point, hold the mouse clicked and move the point somewhere. Like drag and drop.

Thus, somehow I have to technically hook into the "data point clicked" event and also catch the respective mouse move event.

Any ideas how to start?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: I finally moved to Highcharts because I found it to be more mature and capable. Highcharts has a add-on/plug-in named Draggable Points that provides that functionality out-of-the-box

Comment: I wrote a plugin for chart.js called [chartjs-plugin-dragData](https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragData) when I needed the same functionality. The method has been described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062137/6213343